# Angular, webpack: build project into output path

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack

I need to integrate my application client-side part written in Angular with server-side written in Spring. I would like to build the UI project and save in /target folder inside the backend part, so that I could install it using maven then. I'm not sure whether using `ng build --output-path` is still the proper way to do this, while I'm working with @angular ^6.1.0, webpack ^2.7.0, node v8.11.3, npm 6.2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest configuration is to  define where `ng build` generates app files in **angular.json** (replaced .angular-cli.json).

```
 "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/your-app-name",
       // Removed unnecessary code
```

Or you can overwrite the output path using these command line arguments

```
ng build -op dist/example1
ng build --output-path=dist/example2
```

And  `ng build --output-path` is also completely valid option.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've got Type Error: Cannot destructure proprerty 'createHash' of 'undefined' or 'null'. It looks that I need to upgrade my webpack version, which would require further adjustments?

Answer (score 0):

Although [--output-path](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#options) is a completely valid option, it's more comfortable to configure it once in the [Angular CLI workspace (angular.json)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace) file.

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "project-name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```